# What is the cause of the Can't Display Data error message for a Decimal Field in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-fabric

I have a data set that I have created Microsoft Fabric.  It's a relatively small table of invoices that includes Partner_ID, Invoice_ID, Invoice_Date, Due_Date, Invoice_Amt.  The table is part of a dataset that also includes a DIM_Date table and a DIM_Partner table. When I connect to the dataset in Power BI I am able to drag all the Invoice table fields in to a Power Bi table visual except for the Invoice_Amt field. When I drag this field I get an Error:

[image: Error Message and Detail]

I tried a variety of fixes I've seen online including clearing my browser cache, restarting my computer, and recreating the table and dataset.  I also did not find the specific error I got (**file seethru.cpp; line 2162, function 'From FLBA'**) when I was researching the error. Has anyone else come across this error and is there a know fix or workaround? As noted in my question the Invoice_Amt field that casuses the error is a decimal data type.

The Data Model is fairly simple - Many to 1 from Dim_Date to Due_Date and Invoice_Date (both relationships are set to inactive), Many to 1 PartnerID to Partner_ID.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error, I changed the data type of the Invoice_Amt field from decimal to whole number. After this change and a refresh everything worked as expected.

For this particular data set moving to whole numbers is OK, but I'm sure that will not always be the case. Would be nice to know what the issue is with the decimal data type.